# Curious errors when combining inline with explicit member constraints

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, type-parameter

*(Updated: I have added a repro example)*

With code looking like the following:

```
type Lib =
    static member inline tryMe (a: ^a) = 
        let name = (^a: (static member name: string) ())
        name

type Test =
    struct 
        val Value: string
        new v = {Value = v}
    end
    static member inline name with get() = "HiThere"
    static member works(a:Test) = Lib.tryMe a
```

This will "just work" and compile. However, if you extend it a little bit, for instance like as follows:

```
/// Does a bounds check and raises an error if bounds check is not met
let inline checkBounds f (g: 'b -> ^c) (tp: ^a) = 
    let convertFrom = (^a: (static member name: string) ())
    let convertTo = (^c: (static member name : string) ())
    let value =  (^a: (member Value: 'b) tp)
    if f value then
        g value
    else 
        failwithf "Cannot convert from %s to %s." convertFrom convertTo


type ConverterA =
    struct 
        val Value: sbyte
        new v = { Value = v }
    end

    static member inline name with get() = "converter-a"
    static member inline convert (x: ConverterA) : ConverterB = 
        checkBounds ((>=) 0y) (byte >> ConverterB) x

and ConverterB =
    struct 
        val Value: byte
        new v = { Value = v }
    end
    static member inline name with get() = "converter-b"
```

It will raise a whole bunch of spurious FSharp compiler errors.

> error FS1114: The value 'Foo.Bar.name' was marked
>   inline but was not bound in the optimization environment
>
> error FS1113:The value 'name' was marked inline but its 
>   implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not 
>   sufficiently accessible
>
> warning FS1116: A value marked as 'inline' has an unexpected value
>
> error FS1118: Failed to inline the value 'name'
>   marked 'inline', perhaps because a recursive value was marked 'inline'

I haven't seen this happening with other inline functions. I am not sure what happens here. If I change just a little bit, for instance remove the `convertTo` line and its dependencies, it compiles fine.

The errors also don't appear when running the code in FSI, even with FSI set up with `--optimize`.

I can work around it by removing `inline`. For fields of this kind it doesn't matter much anyway, the JIT will inline them, even if F# hasn't.

Is this a compiler bug? Or is there an error in my code, or some restriction on explicit member constraints I haven't been aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder so that the functions you use are known at the point where you use them, otherwise it seems that the F# compiler doesn't know what to inline. As you said in the comments below this answer this is a bug if you ask me.

```
/// Does a bounds check and raises an error if bounds check is not met
let inline checkBounds f (g: 'b -> ^c) (tp: ^a) = 
    let convertFrom = (^a: (static member name: string) ())
    let convertTo = (^c: (static member name : string) ())
    let value =  (^a: (member Value: 'b) tp)
    if f value then
        g value
    else 
        failwithf "Cannot convert from %s to %s." convertFrom convertTo

type ConverterB =
    struct 
        val Value: byte
        new v = { Value = v }
    end
    static member inline name with get() = "converter-b"

and ConverterA =
    struct 
        val Value: sbyte
        new v = { Value = v }
    end

    static member inline name with get() = "converter-a"
    static member inline convert (x: ConverterA) : ConverterB = 
        checkBounds ((>=) 0y) (byte >> ConverterB) x
```

Comment: As indeed with the other question, this solves it as a workaround, but doesn't remove the fact that it's (probably) a bug in F# as order is supposed to be irrelevant here: [my bug report from yesterday](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1565).

Comment: That's true, thanks for reporting. Like I said in the other comment I think the compiler doesn't know what to inline at the point where he tries to inline.