# Using inline within type members fails with FS1114, FS1113, FS1116, FS1118

Tags: f#, inline, type-inference

I've been hit by these errors [before in a much more complex scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440568/curious-errors-when-combining-inline-with-explicit-member-constraints). Since then I have simplified many things and had working code for a long time, until I needed to override `Equals`. It uses an inlined member which F# doesn't seem to be happy about.

Basically, the scenario can be summarized with the following code:

```
[<Flags>]
type MyType =
    | Integer = 0b0001
    | Float   = 0b0010

module Test =
    [<CustomEquality;NoComparison>]
    type SomeType =
        | Int of int64
        | Float of float

        override x.Equals other =
            match other with
            | :? SomeType as y -> 
                // following line throws on compiling this
                match SomeType.getType x &&& SomeType.getType y with
                | MyType.Integer -> int64 x = int64 y       // highest type is integer (both are int)
                | MyType.Float -> float x = float y         // highest type is float (either is or both are float)
                | _ -> false // impossible
            | _ -> false

        override x.GetHashCode() =
            match x with Int i -> hash i | Float f -> hash f

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): float =
            match n with
            | Int i -> float i
            | Float f -> f

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): int64 =
            match n with
            | Int i ->  i
            | Float f -> int64 f

        static member inline getType x =
            match x with
            | Int _ -> MyType.Integer
            | Float _ -> MyType.Float
```

The following errors are raised (this is similar to my previous question but that involved complex ducktyping).

> error FS1114: The value 'Test.SomeType.getType' was marked inline but was not bound in the optimization environment
>   error FS1113: The value 'getType' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible
>   warning FS1116: A value marked as 'inline' has an unexpected value
>   error FS1118: Failed to inline the value 'getType' marked 'inline', perhaps because a recursive value was marked 'inline'

Now, there is no recursive value, and the target type is known (as a result of the implicit cast to `SomeType` in the match pattern), so I don't think there's a reason for this inlining to be impossible.

Does anyone have some thoughts on this? Or a pattern, including the inlined `op_Explicit` (if you remove `getType`, you will get the error on those) and preferably also the `getType` as inlined?

I know I can resolve this with an OO hierarchy, interfaces and what not, but I'd rather use this approach, both for clarity (the type system is a lattice, not a hierarchy) and for performance (an earlier version with the inlining showed more than 4x speed increase in test scenarios, and speed is important).

As an afterthought, the following, simpler scenario also throws these errors:

```
module Test =
    type SomeType =
        | Int of int64
        | Float of float

        static member MyEquals (x, other: SomeType) =
            // following line throws on compiling this
            float x = float other 

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): float =
            match n with
            | Int i -> float i
            | Float f -> f

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): int64 =
            match n with
            | Int i ->  i
            | Float f -> int64 f
```

When I remove the type decoration `other: SomeType`, the error disappears. I don't know why that should matter, as a narrower type with the same statically inferred methods should not raise this error, I'd think.

And since the `override x.Equals` has a type annotation of `obj`, I don't see how I could use that knowledge (remove the type decoration) to help me here.

Comment: You can resolve this by not using `function` and using an explicit argument + `match` instead. `function` yields a value; values cannot be inline. `static member inline getType x = match x with Int _ -> MyType.Integer | Float _ -> MyType.Float`

Comment: @ildjarn, thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't change the errors, try it, copy it in FSI. But you are right, sometimes `inline` works with `function` (static member) and sometimes not (let binding), no idea why, [there's a feature request to allow inlining of `let f = fun x -> ...`](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6237585-allow-inline-keyword-in-the-case-let-f-fun-a), but that's another story. Either way, the errors remain.

Comment: @ildjarn, btw, I updated the Q. (implementing your suggestion), so as there's no confusion where the errors come from. Without compiling, the F# editor, inference and intellisense, do not complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that the F# compiler can't do inlining with unordered code. As you rightly point out in the comment below this appears to be a bug.

```
open System

[<Flags>]
type MyType =
    | Integer = 0b0001
    | Float   = 0b0010

module Test =
    [<CustomEquality;NoComparison>]
    type SomeType =
        | Int of int64
        | Float of float

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): float =
            match n with
            | Int i -> float i
            | Float f -> f

        static member inline op_Explicit(n: SomeType): int64 =
            match n with
            | Int i ->  i
            | Float f -> int64 f

        static member inline getType x =
            match x with
            | Int _ -> MyType.Integer
            | Float _ -> MyType.Float  

        override x.Equals other =
            match other with
            | :? SomeType as y -> 
                // following line throws on compiling this
                match SomeType.getType x &&& SomeType.getType y with
                | MyType.Integer -> int64 x = int64 y       // highest type is integer (both are int)
                | MyType.Float -> float x = float y         // highest type is float (either is or both are float)
                | _ -> false // impossible
            | _ -> false

        override x.GetHashCode() =
            match x with Int i -> hash i | Float f -> hash f
```

Comment: You are correct that this fixes the problem, but the code order is not _incorrect_: inside a class and between classes with `and`, the order is irrelevant. I've [reported this yesterday as a bug to F#](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1565), we seem to have come to roughly the same conclusion :).

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for reporting the bug. My best guess is that the F# compiler even when parsing the module code tried to inline the function without knowing it's implementation, which of course fails.